# How to copy all formulas from a row to another?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'd like to create a new row and then copy all the formulas from the row below to this new row (with relative references, just as if I dragged the formulas manually). My purpose is to copy only the formulas, not the values. I mean, if there is no formula, only a value in the cell below, then the cell above (in the new row) shall be empty. I can have something like this:

```
spreadsheet.getRange('F3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F3'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('H3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('H2:H3'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('L3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('L2:L3'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
```

(As formulas are `F3`, `H3` and `L3`.)

But there I have to change the code every time I change something in the sheet. So I would need something that directly gets and sets all the formulas but only the formulas. Tried to check `getFormulas()` and `setFormulas()` but don't understand how it works.

Comment: .getFormula(), .setFormula(), .getFormulas() and .setFormulas() are parallels to .getValue(), .setValue(), etc. The only difference is that the "Formula(s)" versions get or set formulas while the "Value(s)" versions get or set values. .getRange(), etc., only tells the script where to *look* for values or formulas. That said, what you are trying to do in general seems unnecessary. I'd recommend that you look into the use of array formulas that run from the header cell and produce values for every row of their respective column(s). No need for script.

Comment: If you'd like to post a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it) here, and point out where you are trying to copy these formulas (exact columns), I will be happy to take a look to assess whether array formulas would work in your case. If they will, then you can speed up the sheet, share easily and have less hassle all round as opposed to using scripts.